# SharePoint 2013 Web Application Management: User Policy is grayed out for Central Administration application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointadmin

In the Web Applications Management page of SharePoint Central Administration, the User Policy button is grayed out when the "SharePoint Central Administration v4" application is selected, but this is not the case for any other web application.

The account used to log in is a member of the Farm Administrators group.

I have researched the problem and tried the following solutions:

1. Run "SharePoint 2013 Central Administration" from the start menu
2. Run Internet Explorer as Administrator (then go to Central Administration)
3. Disable UAC

None of these have fixed the problem. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Links to same problem (with solutions):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/203f37d4-dfbe-45d5-8259-8d9acd4b12be/user-policy-is-grayed-out-for-central-administration-v4-web-app?forum=sharepointadminprevious

https://epmgelist.wordpress.com/2013/06/14/central-administration-greyed-out-ribbons-and-missing-functions/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly set a User Policy on the Central Administration web application, but what you can do is set permissions in the same way that you would for other Site Collections.

Go to: Site Settings Icon -> Site Settings -> People and Groups. Then update users/groups/permissions as you would for any other site collection.

These settings won't affect any other sites in the CA web application. To my knowledge, there is no way to set permissions that will affect all sites in the CA web application.